# Delete multiple rows in SQLITE (android)

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to delete all the rows from the table that match the ids in an array. I can do that by either of the below 2 methods (both are working). Can you please advice which one is better?

METHOD 1:

```
public void deleteRec(String[] ids) { //ids is an array
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID+" IN (" + new String(new char[ids.length-1]).replace("\0", "?,") + "?)", ids);
        db.close();
    }
```

METHOD 2:

```
public void deleteRec(String[] ids) { //ids is an array
        String allid = TextUtils.join(", ", ids);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL(String.format("DELETE FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+KEY_ID+" IN (%s);", allid));
       db.close();
    }
```

Comment: For readability, I prefer the 2nd method. But for performance, I don't think it will affect much.

Comment: read about sqlite transactions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just forget about second method!

Your `ids` are all strings from numbers (otherwise SQL would fail), but for generic string data, passing data into SQL statements is never a good idea. Make you application vulnerable to SQL injection:

```
String.format("DELETE FROM t WHERE ID='%s', "1' AND 1=1 --")
// = "DELETE FROM t WHERE ID='1' AND 1=1 --'" => would delete all data!
```

and may fail your SQL statements:

```
String.format("DELETE FROM t WHERE v='%s', "It's me!")
// = "DELETE FROM t WHERE v='It's me!'" => syntactically incorrect (quote not escaped)!
```

EDIT: As `ids` are supplied as string array and probably `KEY_ID` refers a `INT` column, method 1 should be adapted to:

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "CAST("+KEY_ID+" AS TEXT) IN (" + new String(new char[ids.length-1]).replace("\0", "?,") + "?)", ids);
```

Comment: As the documentation (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])) states: "The values will be bound as Strings." This implies that the injection you indicated won't work, it will be interpreted as text and not parsed.

Comment: @AndrasBalázsLajtha Right, but I would rather prefer to use a `CAST` to concatenate strings into SQL.

Comment: The expression `new String(new char[ids.length-1]).replace("\0", "?,")` deserves an explanation: It creates a `char` array with default null(`\0`) values and then replaces these null values with `?,`'s.

Answer (score 5):

Try this maybye it helps you :

```
String[] Ids = ......; //Array of Ids you wish to delete.
String whereClause = String.format(COL_NAME + " in (%s)", new Object[] { TextUtils.join(",", Collections.nCopies(Ids.length, "?")) });
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, whereClause, Ids);
```

Comment: This is what I liked..... it reduces writting for each loop with single steps... ultimately is same.. creates dynamic ? in where clause.

Answer (score 0):

read this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) it says you should not use execSQL with INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE or SELECT because it can be a potential security risk. and still i believe regarding the performance the first one is better.

Comment: The 2nd method could be changed to `db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID+" IN (?)", new String[]{allid} );` to follow the doc.

Comment: @antimo... that's nice & composite .. I'll give a try

Comment: @antimo No it can't!!! There's tons of questions regarding putting arrays into a `IN (...)` clause.

Comment: I guess I was really wrong. The `allid` will be assumed as 1 value since it's escaped by `query()`. Sorry.

Comment: This has nothing to do with security risks; the `insert`/`update`/`delete` functions just can return information that is not available from a generic function like `ExecSQL`.

Answer (score -1):

I used this:

```
String[] Ids = new String[]{"1", "2", "3"};
mContext.getContentResolver().delete(CONTENT_URI, ID + " IN (?, ?, ?)",Ids);
```

the multi ? work.

Comment: Great idea, because you always know how many items you have in your Array. 
And then you enter 500 '?' in arow. But please take care that you did count correctly. -> Ironic OFF.

Answer (score -7):

try this

```
public void deleteRec(String[] ids) { //ids is an array
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        //Your code for delete
    }
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: it will access the database 50 times if I have 50 ids. Not sure whether it is a good idea.

Comment: This does not answer the question, and is worse than both.